# Setting up DNS server inside network

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

OK so here's a little problem I have: I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi as a DNS server (for filtering and caching). The Raspberry Pi is in my network, and has a DHCP IP from the router. The DNS server works perfectly on the Raspberry Pi (I can tell because I set my laptop's DNS server to the local IP of my Raspberry Pi)

However, now I want to set the Raspberry Pi as the DNS server on the router level, so all DHCP clients will use it as their DNS server. The trouble is, if the Raspberry Pi is inside the network, and the network has the Raspberry Pi set as the DNS server, there is no connection to the internet.

Then I thought I'd put the Raspberry Pi outside my main network, on a router that has two clients: the Raspberry Pi and my other router (the main network). However, then I wouldn't be able to access the Raspberry Pi from an IP address set by the inner (main) network.

Basically what I want is the Raspberry Pi to have an IP assigned by the DHCP server on my router (this IP is static), but I want the router to use the Raspberry Pi as it's DNS server (this would mean having the real DNS server only accessible to the Raspberry Pi, and have all other clients use the Raspberry Pi as their DNS server). My router is an Apple Airport Extreme, and I doubt it'd support anything like this (and I'm not sure if anything supports anything like this)..

Is there a way of solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: Does the RaspPi DNS server have request forwarding setup to forward unknown requests to another (external/Internet) DNS server?

Comment: Yes it does, but I think the problem is it can't reach the external DNS server because it's behind a router that is redirecting its DNS requests to the Raspberry Pi itself

Comment: Did you not reference the outside DNS server (for forwards) by IP address?  If so, DNS doesn't play a role in that.

Comment: Yes that's true, it is referenced by IP. That's weird. Thanks

Comment: Weird indeed. :) Maybe your router can't use DNS from it's LAN side. Personally I'd aim to setup the Pi as a DNS server, which forwards to an external DNS server, and then setup the DHCP server to serve the Pi's LAN as address as the DNS server address for the clients, but leave the router's DNS settings to whatever the ISP supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for all the help, I figured out what was wrong.

In the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, `nameserver` was set to the address of my router. This should have been changed to `8.8.8.8` instead, as this will automatically switch dnsmasqs standard lookup address to `8.8.8.8` – whilst still looking for any altered routes in `/etc/hosts`.

Works perfectly now, the only problem is when I reboot the Raspberry Pi, the `resolv.conf` file gets reset. If anyone knows why that's happening or how to fix it that's great, but it's no big deal since I usually only reboot it for updates

Comment: Add the following to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf (change 8.8.8.8 to the IP of your desired DNS server): interface "eth0" {prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;}

This will list 8.8.8.8 as the first nameserver and will also include the nameservers provided by the router.  If you want to not include the domains offered by the router, use "superseded" instead of "prepend".

For reference, see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_dhclien.htm

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues because the web interface on my router is very limited (doesn't allow access to a number of feature like dhcpd.conf).  I got around the issue by installing dnscrypt, which encrypts the outbound queries and forwards them to OpenDNS via port 443.  It's a bit overkill for what you want but it doesn't look like you have that many options.

Answer (score 0):

> In the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, `nameserver` was set to the address of
>   my router. This should have been changed to `8.8.8.8` instead, as this
>   will automatically switch dnsmasqs standard lookup address to
>   `8.8.8.8` – whilst still looking for any altered routes in
>   `/etc/hosts`.

Are you sure about that? Looks to me you are completely by-passing your own local nameserver and using google's instead. Can you give your machines static local IP addresses using the method?

EDIT: here is how you can tell, from [DNSmasq Installation & Configuration](http://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/dnsmasq-installation-configuration-5/#switching), Google Public DNS's respond time is about 36 msec constantly. If you are using google's DNS, your DNS query will always about 36 msec. If you are using your own local nameserver, DNS Query time should be able to drop to near 1 msec. Also serving static IP for your machines is another sure sign.

> I want to set the Raspberry Pi as the DNS server on the router level,
>   so all DHCP clients will use it as their DNS server. The trouble is,
>   if the Raspberry Pi is inside the network, and the network has the
>   Raspberry Pi set as the DNS server, there is no connection to the
>   internet.

My DNSmasq DHCP&DNS server is behind my DSL router, and I'm able to use it to provide DNS to my local machines, while all connections to the internet are fine. Please refer to [DNSmasq Installation & Configuration](http://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/dnsmasq-installation-configuration-5/#switching) for details.

Just a thought.